# Sandy Bridge vs Nehalem: comparable to Pentium M vs Pentium 4?

Tags: intel-pentium

I still remember the huge difference in usability when switching from a Pentium 4 notebook (heavy, hot, low battery life) to Pentium M (light, cool and long battery life).

I am wondering if the current switch to Sandy Bridge is comparable in its impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pentium 4**

- High clock rate which means it
- ran very hot
- wasn't optimized for mobility
- not a notebook processor

**Pentium M**

- A "mobile" processor
- Optimized for battery life
- Specifically targeted for laptops

**Nehalem vs. Sandy Bridge**

Sandy Bridge uses a smaller nm technology for its circuitry over Nehalem, and on a per-clock basis there is some improvement in speed (< 20%). Other than that you won't find the large difference you found when going from Pentium 4 to Pentium M.

What *will* give you a big difference in battery life, power, and maybe even form factor is switching to Sandy Bridge **and** going with a SSD instead of a HDD. Battery life will be a lot longer, you'll use less power (with the same or better performance), and it may even be lighter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I could just get a SSD w/o Sandy Bridge. So you are saying that the difference in battery life due to Sandy Bridge alone are small?

Comment: Compared to Nehalem? Yes. If you have a Nehalem processor or are thinking of getting one, just go with that.

Comment: I should also mention that it depends what sort of Sandy Bridge processor you get. If you get a very high-performance processor compared to a lower-power consumption processor, that obviously makes a difference, since even within SB there are differences among processor classes.